# destructive code by style file

Tags: macros

I'm making a certain program, which is calling LaTeX.
 I'm thinking that this program can include only one style file.

My question is "can we write **destructive** code in style file?". For example, can we write  code for removing file or system?

Answer (score 8):

Yes:

- TeX can open files for writing and therefore overwrite files.
  Depending on the TeX distribution, there might be some security
  restrictions (no files in parent directories, ...).
- There is a shell escape feature (also called "write18"), which can be used
  for malicious code. Again, there are some security restrictions. For example,
  TeX Live only enables restricted shell escape, which only allows a small list
  of configured programs (e.g. kpsewhich, makeindex) to run.

Comment: Thx. I'll research some more deeply about write18 or restructed.